# Reducing CSS code duplication when scoping styles in Vue component

Tags: css, vue.js, webpack, vue-component

It is possible to scope styles in Vue component using this approach:

```
<style scoped src="bootstrap.css"></style>
```

But issue here arises when there are several components on a page using bootstrap and scoping it several times leads to a CSS code duplication issue - bootstrap.css is included multiple times.
Is there a way to reduce such CSS code duplication or is there another way to have scoped CSS?

Building using webpack and gulp task runner through Visual Studio

It is a legacy ASP.NET Web Forms app and importing styles globally breaks page styling.

Holy grail here is that adding scoped reference to bootstrap.css in vue component, but some magic tool/plugin during webpack build step could automatically check what classes are being used and scope (or extract) only those classes only, so code duplication still exists but not that huge as scoping same CSS files several times and  I don't have to pick each of those classes manually and add it to scoped css section. Example of this scenario is .NET assembly weaving.

UPDATE: Ended up with using

```
<style scoped src="bootstrap.css"></style>
```

Comment: Why do you need to scope it instead of importing Bootstrap once globally?

Comment: Importing styles globally conflicts with legacy app styling.

Comment: What style of project is the Vue project? `vue-cli`, `nuxt`, or something different? and how are you compiling and adding it to your existing app?

Comment: You can give custom namespace to the bootstrap library and then use globally.

Comment: Building using webpack and gulp task runner through Visual Studio

Comment: `.customClass{
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
}`
import bootstrap like above and all the classes will come against "customClass" and can be used globally.

Comment: I can't import them globally due to bootstrap conflicting with legacy app. My holy grail here is that I add scoped reference to bootstrap.css in vue component, but some magic tool/plugin during webpack build step could automatically check what classes are being used and scope (or extract) only those classes only, so code duplication still exists but not that huge as scoping same CSS files several times and  I don't have to pick each of those classes manually and add it to scoped css section. Example of this scenario is .NET assembly weaving.